# setcap binary but with arguments?

Tags: linux, capabilities, setcap

I'm trying to start BoringTun with `setcap` in order for it to run unprivileged but still have the ability to `fmark`:

```
root@67672793823c:/# setcap cap_net_admin+epi /usr/local/sbin/boringtun --foreground wgnet0
fatal error: Invalid argument
usage: setcap [-q] [-v] (-r|-|<caps>) <filename> [ ... (-r|-|<capsN>) <filenameN> ]

 Note <filename> must be a regular (non-symlink) file.
```

The man page doesn't seem very helpful and I can't find an option which will allow me to execute a binary with arbitrary arguments.

If I remove the arguments, everything works, but I need to pass these arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setcap` stores the given capabilities in the given file’s metadata (as extended attributes, see [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Capabilities) for details):

```
setcap cap_net_admin+epi /usr/local/sbin/boringtun
```

means that `boringtun` will have those capabilities when it’s run thereafter:

```
/usr/local/sbin/boringtun --foreground wgnet0
```

Comment: Oh, fascinating; it actually writes to the file?

Comment: Not to the file itself, to its extended attributes.